# How to get some fields in Inner Join from django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying get some fields from my database in django.

My model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    product_Description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_Comments = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    product_Status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date_Created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    date_Modified = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_Description
```

My serializers:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'product_Description', 'product_Comments', 'product_Status', 'category', 'date_Created',
                  'date_Modified')

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name')
class InventorySerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_b = CategorySerializer(source="category")
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'product_Description', 'product_Comments', 'product_Status', 'category', 'date_Created',
                  'date_Modified', 'model_b')
```

and my view.py:

```
class inventoryList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.select_related('category')

    print(str(queryset.query))
    serializer_class = InventorySerializers
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.queryset()
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset)
        return obj
```

and it is JSON result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 9,
        "product_Description": "Corbata roja gruesa",
        "product_Comments": "Corbate para ocasiones especiales",
        "product_Status": true,
        "category": 1,
        "date_Created": "2018-07-24T19:53:13Z",
        "date_Modified": "2018-07-24T19:53:13Z",
        "model_b": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Corbata"
        }
    }
]
```

but I need it as:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Corbata",
    "items": {
        "id": 9,
        "product_Description": "Corbata roja gruesa",
        "product_Comments": "Corbate para ocasiones especiales",
        "product_Status": true,
        "category": 1,
        "date_Created": "2018-07-24T19:53:13Z",
        "date_Modified": "2018-07-24T19:53:13Z"
    }
  }
]
```

I was trying in change the serializers like this:

```
class InventorySerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_b = ProductSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'model_b')


class inventoryList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.select_related()
    print(str(queryset.query))
    serializer_class = InventorySerializers
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.queryset()
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset)
        return obj
```

but in this case the query print

```
SELECT "reservation_category"."id", "reservation_category"."name" FROM "reservation_category"
```

in this case the join is not made between my two tables

in this case, how could the query make the from out from "reservation_category" and the join be with the table "reservation_product" like this:

```
SELECT "reservation_product"."id", "reservation_product"."product_Description", "reservation_product"."product_Comments", "reservation_product"."size", "reservation_product"."product_Status", "reservation_product"."category_id", "reservation_product"."date_Created", "reservation_product"."date_Modified", "reservation_category"."id", "reservation_category"."name" 
FROM "reservation_category" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "reservation_product" ON ("reservation_category"."id"  = "reservation_product"."category_id")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off...stylistically...you have an interesting hybrid between CamelCase and snake_case...so I would choose one...typically in Python it's snake_case. (my answer just uses what you put and all my additions are snake_case).

As for the question... this isn't an issue of joins...it's an issue of configuring your serializers correctly.

I'm assuming that what you mean you want is this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Corbata",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "product_Description": "Corbata roja gruesa",
                "product_Comments": "Corbate para ocasiones especiales",
                "product_Status": true,
                "category": 1,
                "date_Created": "2018-07-24T19:53:13Z",
                "date_Modified": "2018-07-24T19:53:13Z"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If that is what you want....I would do the following:

Models (the change here is that I added a `related_name` to the `ForeignKey` which allows you to traverse the backwards relationship with a nicer name (products)...I also removed `category` from the `Product` in this view as it is redundant. Further...instead of the field being called `items` I left it as `products` as that is more descriptive...but obviously you can do what makes sense to you.

```
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):

    product_Description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_Comments = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    product_Status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='products')
    date_Created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    date_Modified = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_Description
```

Serializers (Notice that the category serializer now will have a list of "products")

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'id', 'product_Description', 'product_Comments', 'product_Status', 'category',
            'date_Created', 'date_Modified'
        )

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'products')

    products = ProductSerializer(many=True)
```

View (I have changed the queryset to start with the Category as that is the root object here. I also used `prefetch_related` instead of `select_related` because of the one-to-many relationship here)

```
class inventoryList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = Category.objects.prefetch_related('products')

    print(str(queryset.query))
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.queryset()
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset)
        return obj
```

A couple of things to note...
1. I did not test this code...so the view may need some tweaking (I'm unsure that `get_object` makes any sense here).
2. I consider this somewhat bad API design. I don't like having nested lists of things because it reduces your ability to paginate. If you end up with a lot of categories and then a lot of products in each category, this call could become very expensive and hard to manage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should also add...this is more of a django-rest-framework question than a django question.